# --How do I convert jQuery code in my React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to update the CSS, and naturally I used jQuery, but I'm told not to use jQuery with React.

How would I do this properly.  I can add more code if needed.  I'm simply toggling the bottom border of a div

```
  toggleMarker () {
    if (this.state.previous && (this.state.current !== this.state.previous)) {
      $('#nav_' + this.state.previous).css("border-bottom", '');
    }
    if (this.state.previous !== this.state.current) {
      $('#nav_' + this.state.current).css("border-bottom", this.color);
    }
    this.setState({previous: this.state.current});
  }
```

Comment: What reasons were you given for not using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate components style inline and you can give conditions according to state variables.

**Example**

```
 render(){
    return(
        <div style={{ borderBottom: ((this.state.previous && (this.state.current !== this.state.previous)) ? 'none' : 1) }}>
            // ...
        </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to react, there are many ways to style a component including inline styles, define styles in css and import, using styled components and also using some small JS libraries e.g. [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).

classnames supports any JS expression as class name to your HTML element. You can explore more using above link.

Just a simple example:

```
import styles from './yourcss.css'
import { classnames } from './classnames/bind'
const cx = classnames.bind(styles)

<div className={cx('divStyle')}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have inline CSS with reference from variable in the state. consider this,

```
//define state
this.state={
    toggleState : false}

//have toggler function   
togglerFunction(){
    var temp = this.state.toggleState
    this.setState({
         toggleState : !temp})
}

//in render you can have your element like this
render(){
...
//start of your element suppose a div
{this.state.toggleState == false ? <div style=        
{{borderBottom:"YourValueForFalseHere"}}></div>:<div style=                
{{borderBottom:"YourValueForTrueHere"}}></div>}
//...End of your element
...
}
```